# How to only track my changes?

Tags: microsoft-word, sharepoint

I am helping edit a document in Word on Sharepoint with multiple simultaneous authors. Sections of the document are still being written, so it doesn't make sense to track changes there. Is it possible to only track my changes (or only changes in some sections) so that other users don't have to accept the "changes" they're making, while creating new content?

Comment: Does this do what you want? 1) Open the document 2) Turn on track changes 3) Edit 4) Turn off track changes 5) save and close

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad it's on Sharepoint, so no -- others are in the document at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

In Word, you may accept the changes done by the other reviewers, leaving only
yours as unaccepted.

This is how:

- Ensure the *Review* tab of the ribbon is displayed
- Click the *Show Markup* tool (in Tracking group) and then click *Reviewers*
  to see the list of all the reviewers that made changes to the document
- Make sure a check mark appears next to all reviewers except yourself
- Click the down-arrow under the *Accept* tool in the Changes category
- Choose *Accept All Changes Shown* to accept all the changes shown,
  meaning only those that are selected.